# Can I play Middle Earth, Shadow of Mordor without a mouse?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I only have a macbook pro and only ever use it on my lap on the sofa. Can I play this game without an external mouse or are all fighty twitchy games like this a no go?

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, this game is pretty button intensive.  Mouse movement is used to move the camera & aim your bow, so a reasonable touch-pad should do the job, but I'd be skeptical of one of those middle-of-the-keyboard-eraser things.  Of course two of the buttons the game likes to use *are* the left & right mouse buttons.  You'll want to remap those to something that you can comfortably use along with your laptop's touch-pad.